# How to check Methods in XCTest - Only in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa-touch, xctest

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.lastNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.emailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.retypeEmailTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
}

-(UIImage *)tintImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color {
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
    [imageView setTintColor:color];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage; 
}
```

I could't able to find anywhere in objective c test class.
how to check this method in xctest

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Need to include 
-(void)dismissKeyboard;
in Interface file

XCTest

signup = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CreateAccountViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [signup performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

```
[signup dismissKeyboard];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make them public by adding their signatures in the .h file? If you don't, the test class won't be able to call them.